# =sheet("tabname1").range("table[thatcolumn]") not accepted. Want to change sheetname and search same column in each tab's table

Tags: excel, tabs, range

I need to build a search in the range of `=search("waldo", sheet("tabname1").range("[table1[thatcolumn]]"))`

Table1 exists on all tabs.

What's wrong here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you mean `Range.Find`? *(Sheet.Range("A:A").Find "Waldo")*

Comment: "Table1" can't exist on all tabs. If you did something to convey that impression that should be the reason for your code's failure. Every table has an associated named range, and these names must be unique. Look at your Names Manager to see what's going on in your workbook.

Comment: Variatus: table1 is actually called "Analyzed" . Named Ranges have a scope, global by default.  

udearboy:  I want a pulldown box to select a dataset (one per tab), so I name the tabs to the same name in that pulldown list.  Yes, A:A would work, but I still need to pick the right tab to search.  The sheet(n) construct could be hacked (tab names to sheet numbers mapping), but someone may also add a new tab, and not get how to debug that.  I will use that unless someone comes up with a better flavor of the above.  

I use this expression 1000's of times.  

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't get this to look like anything reasonable.  (Result, eqn):
- 215-0370-000 =INDEX(INDIRECT("A190"),1)
- #FIELD! =range(indirect("datamart!a1:a1")).value
- syntax error =SHEET("0603W").range("a1:a1").value
- Syntax error =range("a1:a1").cell("address")
- 3 =SHEET(INDIRECT("0603W!A1"))
- #NAME? =range(A190).cell("address")
- #NAME? =range(INDIRECT("$A$190:$A$190"))
- 0 =sum(INDIRECT("$A$190:$A$190"))
- 1 =FIND("215-0370-000",INDIRECT("$A$190:$A$190"))
- syntax error 0603W'![analyzed[[#headers], [NVPN]]
- #REF! =SUM(INDIRECT("'0603W'!Analyzed[[#headers],[NVPN]"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://exceloffthegrid.com/turn-string-formula-with-evalute/ shows a VBA "one liner" that can cause Excel to parse any string as if you typed it in a cell.

```
I can now assemble strings with whatever tab/range variations I want, and I get an answer.
```

For example:

```
Tab is 0402, Range is Analyzed, desired column is Number
formula = TABNAME & "!Analyzed[@[Number]]"
EvaluateString(formula) takes "0402!Analyzed[@[Number]]" and gives that cell's value

Function EvaluateString(strTextString As String)
Application.Volatile
EvaluateString = Evaluate(strTextString)
End Function
```

Comment: Oh, and Named Ranges can be local and duplicated on each tab.  But you can't reach from one tab to the other, as far as I can try...